# Finishing an Activity from a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have an Activity that I display as modeless when the phone rings (over the phone app). I would like to finish the Activity when either of the following events occur. The first is if I touch anywhere outside the Activity (this is not a problem), the second is if the ringing stops. I am listening for IDLE_STATE in the broadcast receiver but I am not sure on how to call the finish on the activity when I see it. The receiver is not registered by the activity but by the Manifest.xml

Answer (score 20):

write the code in your receiving broadcast now this will send another broad cast with the intent named "com.hello.action"

```
Intent local = new Intent();
local.setAction("com.hello.action");
sendBroadcast(local);
```

Now catch this intent in the activity with you want to finish it and then call the super.finish() on the onReceive method of your receiver
like this

```
public class fileNamefilter extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction("com.hello.action");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();

    }
};

public void finish() {
    super.finish();
};
}
```

this will finish the activity

Answer (score 0):

What if you register another broadcast receiver from the activity. Then, when you want to kill it, send a broadcast message from the broadcast receiver that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up adding a PhoneStateListener in the Activity to listen for IDLE_STATE.

Answer (score 0):

After a long R&D over internet i have solved my problem. The below code is helpful if you start an activity from broadcast receiver and
 clear all activity stack instance.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to solve my problem. `finish` is the method of `Activity`, so call `Activity` and context like:

```
if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
     Log.e(TAG, "Inside EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
     ((Activity) arg0).finish();
}
```