# Finishing an activity from BroadcastReceiver - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finishing an Activity from a Broadcast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563301/finishing-an-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver)

Please observe the scenario I have:

Class A extends Activity

Class B extends BroadcastReceiver

How can I finish Activity A from Class B's onReceive method? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486865/remove-or-close-your-own-activity-window-from-a-status-bar-notification-intent/ is helpful

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with this is to register a broadcast receiver in code inside your activity and listen for that particular broadcast message for which you want to finish your activity.

P.S. Independent *Broadcast-Receivers* and *Services* don't have right to manipulate *Activities*, except for launching Activities as new task.