# How to close previous activities when activity launch by intent-filter happens?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

I have an Activity, that launches from browser by this intent-flter:

```
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
            <data android:host="someaction"/>
            <data android:path="/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But if i have other activities of my app not destroyed, they will appear behind launched activity. I need somehow use CLEAR_TOP flag but with intent filter. Activity's launchMode was set to `singleTop`
and i can't use singleInstance or singleTask. So how can launch only my desirable activity and not the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

I'd try this with some `BroadCast` event. Send one from the `Activity` you start, and add `BroadcastReceivers` to the ones you'd like to close.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563301/finishing-an-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver), I think it should help you.

**Solution 2**

I would also give this a try: set you activity's intent flag as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. Also you can consider using the following intent flags: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: nice solution, but with switching activities animation - previous activity is visible some time, before destroying

Comment: Try with overriding pending animations: [link](http://foobarpig.com/android-dev/how-to-disable-animation-on-startactivity-finish-and-backpressed.html)

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe that flag could also do for you.

Comment: i can't use CLEAR_TOP flag or override pending animations cause i don't launch activity explicitly, instead i'm using intent filter and user launch my activity from browser

Comment: Create a dummy activity with intent filters only, which starts your real activity with CLEAR_TOP flag. Ovveride pending transition between the dummy and real, so no visible trace would remain after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95287/discussion-between-lester-and-abbath).