# Finish activity started from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my android app, I want to use broadcast receiver to check network state.
SO till now I have created a broadcast receiver using,

```
    public class NetworkChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo ni=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if(ni!=null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting())
            {
                //here i want to close the activity which is open from the else block
            }
            else
            {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,NetworkDialog.class);
                mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(mIntent);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see in above code, I am calling the Networkdialog activity in else block.
I would like to mention that,
the NetworkDialog.class is a activity, but I have set its style as Dialog, using below code in manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".NetworkDialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="You are Offline"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

now, the problem is, this activity is calling successfully when network is not available,
but when the user connects to internet, I am unable to finish this activity.

(Note- As we all know, the broadcast receiver works globally, means it will work even if your app is not active, so to prevent this, I am not registering the receiver in manifest file, I am registering and unregistering it in the activity where I want to use that receiver)

SO I just want to ask is, how can I finish that dialog activity in first if block, which is called from intent in else block

***Here is my updated code***

NetworkDialog.java

```
    public class NetworkDialog extends AppCompatActivity {
    public IntentFilter filter;

    BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Toast.makeText(context,"Finish Activity here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.network_dialog);
        setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

        filter=new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.hello.action");
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver class

```
    public class NetworkChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo ni=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if(ni!=null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting())
            {
                Intent local=new Intent();
                local.setAction("com.hello.action");
                context.sendBroadcast(local);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,NetworkDialog.class);
                mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(mIntent);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I havent changed any other file

Comment: Send a `Localbroadcast` using `LocalbroadcastManager`

Comment: will you please tell me how can I use it

Comment: Refer this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563301/finishing-an-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public class NetworkChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
    @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
    if(intent.getExtras() != null)
    {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo ni=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(ni!=null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        {
            //here You need to call local broadcast receiver
            // Like this 
               Intent local = new Intent();
               local.setAction("com.hello.action");
               sendBroadcast(local);


        }
        else
        {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,NetworkDialog.class);
            mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(mIntent);

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Code For dialog activity

```
   public class YourDialogActivity extends Activity {
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

     @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

      filter.addAction("com.hello.action");
      registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    }
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       finish();

      }
    };

    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        };
   }
```

Comment: sorry but no luck...nothing happend at all

Comment: i tried displaying toast in onrecieve of the broadcast reciver of dialog activity... but i thing using above code, the receiver is not calling properly

Comment: please see my updated question. i have posted my new code according to your suggestion

Comment: <receiver android:name=".network.backgroundService.NetworkAccessBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Have you register this receiver in manifest file.

Comment: thank you so much...my mistake. actually i was trying to register and unregister receiver in every activity. by mistake i forgot to add it in dialog activity... by adding register and unregister receiver code in diloag activity worked for me

Comment: Then better option is you can register that receiver in manifest file rather than in every activity.

Comment: but registering receiver in manifest popup dialog even if app is not active