# How to close app from notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

My Android app runs 50% of the time in background, and has a notification that, when I press it, pops up the main activity `BusMap` via a `PendingIntent`. Now, I also want to close the app when I remove the notification by sliding it to prevent it to run in the background. I don't want to create broadcasts just for this. I tried adding `.setDeleteIntent(quitpendingintent)` to the same notification builder, but failed.

Is there a "natural" way to do this?

Comment: What does "close the app" mean? What does "but failed" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare: "close the app" = System.exit(0); "but failed" = not System.exit(0);. I know this is not the supposed way for an Android app to "close", but I prefer it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no Intent flag/mechanism that ends an `Activity` like you want so I think the easiest and cleanest way to do that is to use a `BroadcastReceiver` and finish the activity from there.

From what you posted I think you know the way to do this using `BroadcastReceiver` but just in case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413702/6248510) is a way to do that.

Comment: I didn't want to implement a `BrodcastReceiver` just to finish the activity.... but ok. I implemented the `BrodcastReceiver` through a `.setDeleteIntent(intent)` in the `Notification.builder`. Thanks!